# C# DataGridView adding data doesn't work with special character column headers

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, special-characters

Following problem:
I'm trying to fill a `DataGridView` with values:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
dataGridView1.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth(DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders);
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = true;

//creating columns
List<string> keys = new List<string> { "Äpfel", "C", "Käse", "Bögen", "E" };
foreach (string key in keys)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column.HeaderText = key;
    column.Name = key;
    column.DataPropertyName = key;
    column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
    column.ReadOnly = true;
    column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
}

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (string key in keys)
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(key, typeof(int)));      // 2

//filling with data
int num = 1;
List<int> resTypes = Res.All;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    object[] values = new object[keys.Count];
    for (int j = 0; j < keys.Count; j++)
        values[j] = num++;

    dt.Rows.Add(values);
}
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

The problem seems to be the word "Äpfel" which seems to have some obscure influence on the values of the other columns.

The result looks like following:

[image]

Column "C" and "Bögen" received the values of "Äpfel".
Why does this happen and is there any easy way to solve it?

**Edit:**

I tried different changes and the problem turned out to be hard to reproduce. Even slight changes lead to unpredictable changes and I couldn't figure out what was causing them.

However in certain cases, it made a difference if the gridview was already visible or not when I was calling the filling function. Since I used it in a TabControl, it was not visible all the time.
In certain cases it failed when calling it before making it visible and worked afterwards.

I ended up removing the DataTable stuff and adding the values directly via

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(values);
```

which so far seems to solve the problem

**Edit 2:**

Seems like using a DataTable to add data caused several problems. Replacing it solved some other issues with the row headers, which weren't displayed or vanished when sorting rows

Comment: I tested the code, but it works fine. The first row data is `1 2 3 4 5`.

Comment: Damn, what the heck. Have you tried it with .Net 3.5 ?  Or could the occurence of this error dependend on standard language settings?

Comment: Tested it both in .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.7.2. And the CurrentCulture is en-US.

Comment: Changed only 'Äpfel' to 'Aepfel' and it works. back again and it failed

Comment: Do note that the column __Names__ and the column __Headers__ are __totally different__ things, but the header text defaults to the column name.. (I always avoid umlaute etc in system object names.)